# Alternative to didexitregion when monitoring ibeacon

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I have a program in swift that detect when a beacon is in range and out of range even though the app is in background.
The problem I have is it takes about 30 secs for didExitRegion to get triggered. I know this 30 secs is a non-adjustable value, but for my app, 30 secs is a long way to walk away from the beacon to get notification. What other alternative I have to solve this issue? 
Is it possible to monitor for a Major value while the app is in the background, and give it like 10 secs for false positive and if still not seeing the major value, then I know I am out of range?
If answer is yes, any sample to show as how to monitor on the major value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The alternative is to do beacon ranging**, and create your own exit event when you haven't seen any beacons in the region for a smaller time period, say 10 seconds.

However, there is a big limitation to doing this:

In the background on iOS, you can only range for beacons for a limited time period after a region entry event, or after the app gets pushed to the background.  By default, this is only 5 seconds, but it can be [extended up to 3 minutes programatically](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html).  After that three minutes, you won't get any more ranging callbacks, so if you haven't detected a 10-second exit by that time, then you will have to rely on the regular `didExitRegion` event.

If you use this technique, you need to realize that iOS still reports the presence of the beacon for awhile after it has not been detected, with a proximity of UNKNOWN.

Here is an example of how to do this in your ranging callback:

```
var lastBeaconDetectionTime = 0.0
var exitFired = false

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
  for beacon in beacons {
    if beacon.proximity != CLProximity.Unknown {
      lastBeaconDetectionTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
      exitFired = false
    }
  }
  if NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 - lastBeaconDetectionTime > 10.0 && !exitFired {
    exitFired = true
    // TODO: Add logic for region exit firing after 10 seconds
  }
}
```